# Autoscaling policy not launching new instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-auto-scaling

I have setup different types of dynamic scaling policies within my autoscaling group that uses a launch template to try and see autoscaling launch new instances when these are triggered, but it doesn't do it. I just set up the following tracking policy, and here are the results:

[The tracking policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsGZz.png)

[Alarm is in-alarm stated, and action was "Successfully executed"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiRof.png)

[Autoscaling activity is not reporting anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN04h.png)

The alarm always logs that an autoscaling action was triggered, however autoscaling does not log any activity.

This autoscaling group is set up with min: 1, max:6, currently there is only 1 instance running.

Where or how can I find the error that is causing this? Is it perhaps something related to permissions? All instances are healthy/in-service

Spent the past couple of days going through threads on stackoverflow and other forums and haven't found anything that can help me find where the issue is.

Also, the timestamps differ in the screenshots as I had just done a re-deployment, but it is the same behavior all the same before I had done that, there is never activity on the autoscaling instance from the action launched within the alarm...

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your scaling policy and environment:-

- Created an ASG
- assigned a tracking policy of 0.0001

My max capacity is 2, desired 1 and minimum 1.

The key point here is to **wait** for Cloudwatch ALarms to collect data from data points, for my scale-out activity it took around 5 minutes (the majority of the time is taken in warm up of instances too )

Comment: In my case no matter how long I wait, it does not launch new instances unfortunately. Not sure if it is permission related, I have set up policies for cpu, network in and out, application load balancer request count per target, and made sure they were all triggered.

I am not sure if there is a permissions issue which causes cloudwatch alarm not to reach autoscaling somehow.

I have waited for hours and nothing.

Comment: its probably your launch template configuration https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ts-as-instancelaunchfailure.html

check these, it could due to instance configuration or their ami

Comment: Create a new launch template should solve this issue

Comment: I also thought that could be, but I can't find anything wrong, and if I manually right click on the policy, select options, click "Execute", set a number manually, and save, then autoscaling executes it. This is such a strange situation as there are no errors logged anywhere... It even shows as if it succeed (from the alarm logs). On my personal account where I give all permissions to everything this autoscaling setup is working, but on this other account it isn't, and I can't even see if it is actually a permissions issue in order to be able to give whatever role the permissions it needs.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the reason of this issue, under the autoscaling group, go to **Details**, then to **Advanced configurations** and then to **Suspended processes**, nothing should be selected in this field, in my case alarms was set there along a few other actions, that is the reason autoscaling wasn't running on cloudwatch alarms.

[Autoscaling group advanced configurations section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIBkf.png)